# Understanding the .NET implementation of HashTable and its bucket reuse

Tags: .net, hashtable

The implementation of .NET's `HashTable.Insert` has the following line preceding the actual insertion operation:

```
int emptySlotNumber = -1; // We use the empty slot number to cache the first empty slot. 
                          // We chose to reuse slots create by remove that have the 
                          // collision bit set over using up new slots.
```

Moving forward to the `do-while` loop performing the actual insertion, we have two conditions that check this potential reusing possibility; They both check whether the bucket once contained an entry but is now available, and differ in checking whether the collision bit is set (first `if`) or not (second `if`):

here is the first `if`:

```
if (emptySlotNumber == -1 && (buckets[bucketNumber].key == buckets) &&
                                                 (buckets[bucketNumber].hash_coll < 0))
```

and the second one (please ignore the checking precdeing the `||` operator, this is irrelevant to my question):

```
if ((buckets[bucketNumber].key == null) || // please ignore this line
    (buckets[bucketNumber].key == buckets && 
              ((buckets[bucketNumber].hash_coll & unchecked(0x80000000))==0)))
```

It is worth mentioning that `HashTable.Remove` initializes the `hash_coll` field with a reference to `buckets` if the bucket has the collision bit set:

```
// Clear hash_coll field, then key, then value
buckets[bn].hash_coll &= unchecked((int)0x80000000);
if (buckets[bn].hash_coll != 0) {
    buckets[bn].key = buckets;
} 
else {
    buckets[bn].key = null;
}
buckets[bn].val = null;
```

My question is: How does this implementation contributes to the performance of using `HashTable`? I'd be thankful for an example demonstrating what may happen if a HashTable's bucket implementation couldn't have had <sub><sup>(hope this is the right grammatical tense)</sup></sub> the value of `buckets[bn].key = buckets` (but only a 'noraml' value or `null` if removed).

Comment: I don't know the answer but you will enjoy the implementation of Dictionary. It does not need a fill factor which most hash tables do. It uses chaining, but it efficiently stores the linked lists in a single array. It cleverly adds removed buckets to a linked list tracking free buckets. I have never seen this before and I find it to be a superior hash table design.